# Why my subscription function is not called when I execute a 'next' method on subject

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs

I want to make a backend validation on a field of my form and for that I made a
hook that will listen to the changes of this field and on some conditions must make a backend call.

Here is the React hook that I defined.

*useOnChangeDebounce.ts file*

```
export default function (callBack: (v: string | undefined) => void, time = 500) {
    const subject = new Subject<string | undefined>()
    useEffect(() => {

        const sub = subject
            .pipe(
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                debounceTime(time)
            )
            .subscribe(callBack)

        return () => {
            sub.unsubscribe()
        }
    }, []);
    return (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        subject.next(e.target.value)
    }
}
```

in component:

```
...
    const valueChange = useOnChangeDebounce((v) => {
        // this part is not executed when I type in the input
        console.log(v)
    })
    return (
    ...
       <input type="text" onChange={valueChange}/>
    ...
   )
...
```

Comment: @MilanDev ??? Nobody should trust a stranger to take over their computer.

Comment: Is unsubscribe called for some reason?

Comment: Can you clarify and make it overtly clear if `useOnChangeDebounce` from the second snippet is the code of the first snippet? Can you provide a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we've better context what the code is doing?

Comment: useOnChangeDebounce is effectively code of the first snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use useMemo with empty dependency to keep the subject reference otherwise it will create new instance every time when hook will be invoked try `const subject = useMemo(() => new Subject(), [])`.

Comment: Thanks, this suggestion worked, it was indeed the mistake I was making